# How is arm trusted OS is different from normal OS?

Tags: operating-system, arm, processor

I am going through the arm trusted firmware architecture from this link https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/docs/firmware-design.rst and I am confused. I have below queries:-

1. What is the need of trusted OS ?
2. How it is different from normal world OS ?
3. If trusted OS is secure then why not only use trusted OS and remove normal OS ?
4. from what threats the trusted OS give security and how ?
5. When is the switch between trusted OS and normal world is required ?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to first read the introductory article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_execution_environment), then the [notice about OP-TEE](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/blob/3.1.0/Notice.md), which is an implementation running on Cortex-A processors, now maintained by Linaro, then the various documentations available [here](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/tree/3.1.0/documentation), and finaly look at the [OP-TEE code](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/tree/3.1.0) itself.
Now, rather concise answers to your questions could be:

*1) What is the need of trusted OS ?*
The need is to prevent resources from being directly accessed from the generalist OS it is running concurrently with, for example by a user of the generalist OS having root privileges.  
*2) How it is different from normal world OS ?*
It is small by design, and running with more privileged access to the hardware than the generalist operating system. On an ARMv8-a system, portions of the Trusted OS will run at EL3, when an hypervisor will run at EL2, and Linux at EL1.
*3) If trusted OS is secure then why not only use trusted OS and remove normal OS ?*
Because of its limited scope: its purpose is not to replace, say, Linux, which has millions of line of working/well tested code, but to secure resources from Linux users at a small cost.
*4) From what threats the trusted OS give security and how ?*
From attempts from the generalist OS users, either legitimate, or illegitimate (hackers having compromised the generalist OS for example), to access resources/services protected by the Trusted OS.
*5) When is the switch between trusted OS and normal world is required ?*
It is required at the time some code running in the context of the generalist operating system will need to access a resource managed by the Trusted OS, for example having some encrypted content decrypted using a key which is  only accessible by the Trusted OS. This does involve (I think) the use of  the SMC instruction.
An other occurence of such a switch is when a hardware interrupt needs to be handled: EL3, EL2 and EL1 have their own interrupt vectors tables, and interrupts happening at EL2 or EL1 can be routed to EL3, so that interrupt handling may be safely handled in the context  of the Trusted Execution Environment - thanks to artless noise for reminding me about this.

Comment: For answer '5', the trusted OS may need to service interrupts which will result in a world switch.  The trusted OS is a **layering** security mechanism.  Ex, a file system restricts access based on user privilege yet shares the same physical hard drive.  **If** the file system software works properly you can make assumptions about who can/can not read, write and modify files.  Trustzone allows layering of CPU and hardware resources in a manner that prevents DMA attacks.

Comment: @artless noise - you are perfectly right, thank you - I augmented answer to #5 accordingly.